# How can I work out how long I've been an Ubuntu Member for?

Tags: ubuntu-membership

Like a lot of the users here, I've gone through the steps to become an [Ubuntu Member](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership). I won't reiterate the details of what that means but recently it was announced that [certificates would be available for Members](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/06/14/certificates-for-ubuntu-members/) and I'd like to cash that chip in now.

The problem is [the form](https://forms.canonical.com/certificate/) asks when I became a Member... And I'm not sure. I suspect it somewhere in October 2011 because that's the last time I edited my wiki page.

Is there a public registration of Ubuntu members that includes their registration dates?

Comment: Hmm, after all that the form now squawks back: "The date must be after 01/01/2013" || Edit: It seems to work now.

Comment: What? I've sent this form from day one, and I hadn't any problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you became an Ubuntu Member through the direct way you can see when, in Launchpad. On [memberships page](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntumembers/+members#active) mentions **"Member Since"**

If you became an Ubuntu Member through the indirect way (ubuntuforums.org), then you can search for your application in UbuntuForums and check the last message.
For example my application is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2071185&page=4&s=81d6f3aef491a1f1fd682882d8bac5e6) and the last message from Elfy indicates that I became a member in November 17th 2012. Alternatively, a page exist in Launchpad for [Ubuntu Forums Members](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-forum-members/+members#active)

Answer (score 6):

Launchpad keeps this information. Take a look at `https://launchpad.net/~you/+participation`. Start from "Ubuntu Members". If you are an indirect member (or became a member indirectly), then you may not see a join date, but you will see the groups that cause you to be an indirect member. These should lead "recursively" to a series of join dates, and the earliest one is the date when you became a member.

Answer (score 4):

For a hacky way, [Googling `site:irclogs.ubuntu.com  congratulations oli`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3airclogs.ubuntu.com%20congratulations%20oli) shows links me to the `#ubuntu-meeting` log where people were congratulating me for becoming a member.